# Django-Mongo Model Default behavior when refactoring

Tags: django, mongodb, django-models

I'm not entirely sure how this engine works, but let me set up a scenario. I have a Django-Mongo project with say a model class like:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now=True)
```

I create a bunch of base models and everything is all lovely in the project and I get lots of data. Then, later the project grows and we need to expand BaseModel. It suddenly becomes:

```
class BaseModel(models.Model):
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now_add=True)
    modified_at = models.DateTimeField(null=False, auto_now=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

So I get that mongo will allow me to change this without having to touch the database, but say the very next thing I do is do a query like:

```
BaseModel.objects.filter(active=True)
```

Should I expect old records that needed to use the default but have not been access yet to show up in this query? Or do I need to do anything specific for the query engine to realize that the value I'm looking for matches the default?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found the answer out after some trial and error. When Django executes the query, it looks against what Mongo has in the database and ignores any default settings. However, when you already get an object, Django puts the default into the object in memory (but not in the Mongo record).

This seems kind of gross. What it means is, before we can query upon that refactored field we need to do something like this once:

```
for mod in BaseModel.objects.all():
    mod.save()
```

Needless to say, this is a really really expensive query potentially. Thankfully it only has to be run once, but still.

If there are better alternatives that'd be great.

Comment: That's just how MongoDB works. Maybe you could use something like "all objects that have `active=True OR active=None`"

Comment: Meh, not sure how I feel about altering a bunch of queries making them permanantly more expensive for a one time backwards compatibility issue